# Possible Bug in Spring '20 - Process builder formula doesn't save BR()

Tags: formula, process-builder, html, richtextarea, spring-20

Since being upgraded to the Spring '20 release, a process that we have has stopped saving BR() in a formula to the Rich Text field it is populating.

Formula in Process:

```
"... next steps." + BR() + "<b>Next Step - ..."
```

Spring 20 saved value on record:

```
"... next steps.<b>Next Step - ..."
```

Furthermore, the saved value is different in scratch orgs:

```
"... next steps.<br>&lt;/b&gt;Next Step - ..."
```

Winter 20 saved value:

```
"... next steps._BR_ENCODED_<b>Next Step - ..."
```

The last known time we have it saving correctly is Friday before our Spring 20 release. We began having abnormal results the morning after the release. The last time this process was modified was 12/18/2019.

I found this [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000003dMMQAY&title=line-break-in-text-area-is-not-rendered-when-text-area-is-referred-from-formula-and-formula-include-br-function) that seems related but apparently my org has been fixed.

Is it possible this bug was introduced in the fix of this known issue? Was there a change in behaviour that I missed included with this release? Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using rich text fields with process builder formulas, we found that the best option was the the string value of `<br />` in the rich text field.

This solution ended up providing us with the desired results in the format in which we needed it to display (email body text).